# Como esconder minha label após a seleção do input?

Tags: html, css

Olá, criei um input de texto, e gostaria de esconde-lo após o usuário seleciona-lo para o preenchimento. Alinhei uma label dentro do input simulando um placeholder.(Escolhi essa opção para facilitar a estilização dele), mas quando coloco o `display:none;` após o focus nada acontece, qual a forma mais eficiente de esconder minha label ?

```css
#config {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#646464;
  text-align: center;

}

input {
  border: 2px solid #646464;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;

}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 10px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5),
              0px 0px 15px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5);
}
input:focus > label {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: text;
  z-index: -1;
}


label::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f4ff";
}

#lbl-score::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f091";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/teste.css' >
        <link rel="icon" href="CSS/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/fontawesome-free-5.11.2-web/css/all.css'>
        <title>Dice - The Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <section id='config'>
            <h1 id='text'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Change or modify the name of the players</h1>
            <label id='lbl-player-0'> Name Player 1</label><input id='ipt-player-0' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
            <label id='lbl-player-1'> Name Player 2</label><input id='ipt-player-1' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
            <h1 id='text'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Reset the Winner conditions</h1>
            <label id="lbl-score"> Score for Winner</label><input id='ipt-score' type='number'class="ipt-name-change"></input>
          
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que quer fazer não me parece viável porque quando o input perder o `focus`, a `label` voltará a aparecer por cima do que foi digitado no input. Teria que fazer um controle adicional via JavaScript pra isso funcionar.

Se quiser fazer só com CSS, use o atributo `placeholder` e coloque cada input dentro da sua label e acrescente um `<span></span>` que receberá o ícone. O `span` irá ficar fixo dentro e à esquerda do input e o espaço restante será para digitação.

Usei `text-indent` para dar espaçamento interno nos elementos. Creio que desta forma fica mais fácil e, na minha opinião, mais amigável:

```css
#config {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#646464;
  text-align: center;
}

#config input {
  border: 2px solid #646464;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: 40px;
}

#config input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 10px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5),
              0px 0px 15px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5);
}

#config label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#lbl-player-0 span::before,
#lbl-player-1 span::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f4ff";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#lbl-score span::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f091";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#config label span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   text-indent: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id='config'>
   <h1 id='text'>
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Change or modify the name of the players
   </h1>
   <label id='lbl-player-0'>
      <input placeholder="Name Player 1" id='ipt-player-0' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
      <span></span>
   </label>

   <label id='lbl-player-1'>
      <input placeholder="Name Player 2" id='ipt-player-1' class="ipt-name-change" required></input>
      <span></span>
   </label>
   <h1 id='text'>
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Reset the Winner conditions
   </h1>
   <label id="lbl-score">
      <input placeholder="Score for Winner" id='ipt-score' type='number'class="ipt-name-change" required></input>
      <span></span>
   </label>
</section>
```

Comment: Muiito Bom, achei que realmente teria que apelar para o js,não tinha pensado em fazer dessa forma ficou mais pratico